# Shell command/workaround to turn quoted strings into normal strings

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, echo

I'm writing a shell script that outputs all untranslated strings from gettext .po file, and stuck on a simple thing. At the end of my commands chain I get such output:

```
"less than a minute left"
"%d minutes left"
"logged in as <a href=\"%s\">%s</a>"
"more"
```

And I don't know how to echo these lines without quotes, like this:

```
less than a minute left
%d minutes left
logged in as <a href="%s">%s</a>
more
```

Note, that quotes are used inside phrases, so I can't just remove them by sed. I wish I knew a command that unquotes such. Something more injection-safe than

```
 awk '{ print "echo ", $0}' | sh
```

Just in case here's a working demo of what I have so far:

```
 wget https://raw.github.com/vslavik/poedit/master/locales/wa.po
 msgattrib --untranslated --no-wrap wa.po | grep msgid | sed "s/msgid[^ ]*//"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `'s/^\s"\|"$//g'` and `'s/\\"/"/g'` to your sed command should strip off the leading and trailing `"`, and also convert all `\"` to `"`.

Full command:

```
msgattrib --untranslated --no-wrap wa.po | grep msgid | sed 's/msgid[^ ]*//; s/^\s"\|"$//g; s/\\"/"/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess this should be ok:

```
msgattrib --untranslated --no-wrap wa.po | grep msgid | sed "s/msgid[^ ]*//"|sed -e 's/^\s"//' -e 's/"$//'
```

**edit**

this time?

```
    msgattrib --untranslated --no-wrap wa.po | grep msgid | sed "s/msgid[^ ]*//"\
|sed -e 's/^\s"//' -e 's/"$//' -e's/\\"/"/g'
```

Comment: It doesn't replace \"%s\" to "%s" inside phrases :(